# Business network definition error - Hyperledger blockchain / IBM zerotoblockchain training

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I am learning Hyperledger blockchain, and trying to follow ZerotoBlockchain
(https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/crse0401.html?Open)

I've installed all components, but I got following error when I ran the "buildAndDeploy" script file from MyPath/ZeroToBlockchain/Chapter03. I am using MacOSX.

- docker and fabric is running.
- before getting this error, everything was done successfully.

The error is as follows:

---

> ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>
> Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers.
>
> Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: **Error
>   starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build:
>   Error returned from build: 1 "#
>   composer/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3**
>
> In file included from
>   chaincode/input/src/composer/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/api.go:7:0:
>
> chaincode/input/src/composer/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/api.go:
>   In function '_duk_error':
>
> chaincode/input/src/composer/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/duktape.h:510:127:
>   warning: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
>   [-Wunused-value]   (duk_error_raw((ctx), (duk_errcode_t) (err_code),
>   (const char *) (DUK_FILE_MACRO), (duk_int_t) (DUK_LINE_MACRO),
>   **VA_ARGS**), (duk_ret_t) 0)
>                                                                                                                                  ^
>
> chaincode/input/src/composer/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/api.go:153:2:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'duk_error'   duk_error(ctx, err_code,
>   "%s", str);   ^
>
> go build composer: /opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: fork/exec
>   /opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: exec format error "
>
> Command failed
>
> ---

Comment: I found some strange thing. "**go build composer: /opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link**", regarding this error, actually my go env parameter is different from it. "go env" command shows results of **"GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.4/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"** I have no idea why the command path is different from my go environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but resolved it by adding path to go.
In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

# which go

/usr/local/go/bin/go

vi .profile

PATH="**ADD THIS TO YOUR PATH** /usr/local/go/bin"

# source .profile

# buildAndDeploy

```
   =====================================================
   -----> starting REST server
   =====================================================

   network archive, start and deploy script for the Zero To Blockchain Series
   This has been tested on Mac OSX thru High Sierra and Ubuntu V16 LTS
   This script will create your Composer archive
```

Parameters:
       Network Name is:  zerotoblockchain-network
       =====================================================
       -----> testing rest server
        when this completes,
         go to your favorite browser
        and enter localhost:3000/explorer
       =====================================================
       =====================================================
       -----> starting rest server v0.15 for admin@zerotoblockchain-network
       =====================================================
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer

Open the browser and you'll see exactly like the video.

Comment: Hi Steve, I added go path already. But now I have a confidence that go path is causing this problem. Many thanks.